# accessing arrays within NSMutabale array

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, xcode, parse-platform

I have a NSMutableArray which stores multiple arrays, so my array looks like this:

array: deals

1. [0]

   - [0] ID
   - [1] NAME
   - [2] DESCRIPTION
   - [3] PRICE
2. [1]

   - [0] ID
   - [1] NAME
   - [2] DESCRIPTION
   - [3] PRICE
3. [2]

   - [0] ID
   - [1] NAME
   - [2] DESCRIPTION
   - [3] PRICE

How can I drill down into the array to access in information such as [1][NAME]?

I have tried nesting objectAtIndex but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have been able to access elements in an`NSMutableArray` using the shorthand accessors `[]` in objective-c for a while now (so shouldn't need `objectAtIndex`).

```
NSString *name = myArray[1][1];
```

This is equivalent to:

```
NSArray *entry = myArray[1];
NSString *name = entry[1];
```

Should be enough to access the **NAME** entry you are looking for.

If this isn't working, verify that the elements are actually `NSArray` objects and not `NSDictionaries` - if they are, you would use something more like:

```
NSDictionary *entry = myArray[1];
NSString *name = entry[@"NAME"];
```